# How to click on an ID of another page

Tags: css, slider

I've created a slider using swiper in a page called product.html(this page is a vertical slider with pagination [see example](http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/03-vertical.html)),  and In index.html(my main page where I list all the products) when I click on a link product2 it should redirect to slide 2.  I've tried `<a href="product.html#slide2"`. it works but it doesn't load the whole slider. I can't slide and it doesn't show the pagination
How do I navigate to a specific slide with swiper loading and showing pagination?

swiper structure

```
<!-- Swiper -->
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide" id="slide1">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" id="slide2">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide" id="slide3">Slide 3</div>
                        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I see the pagination on my screen?  Could be a screen res issue?

Comment: I can also click and drag in chrome, what device, screen size do you have?

Comment: which slide did you click on? it works for slide1 but not other slides. I'm creating a fully responsive website. it doesn't work on all screen sizes(from chrome toggle device toobar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code**

Passing `index` of slider

```
<div class="product-list">
     <a href="product.html#2">product3</a>
     <a href="product.html#5">product6</a>
     <a href="product.html#10">product10</a>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/2XSodBJCUObqcljzhiot?p=preview)

Passing `id` of slider

```
<div class="product-list">
     <a href="product.html#slide2">product2</a>
     <a href="product.html#slide5">product5</a>
     <a href="product.html#slide10">product10</a>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/UC7fluB1uNtzcmjrYMGE?p=preview)

Comment: Glad to help you